# Element class not change

Tags: jquery, css, class

im try change the class of a element, via JQuery.
I have a datatable with sortable columns, this is an example of a sortable column html:

```
<th>
   <a href="#">Fecha</a>
   <i class="icon-arrow-up pull-right"></i>
</th>
```

So, when click the anchor, an event is fired and execute the sort:

```
sort: function(){
    if(this.parent.collection.sortAttribute === this.idx){
        this.parent.collection.sortDirection *= -1;
    }
    this.changeSortIcon(this.$el.find('i'));
    this.parent.collection.sortBy(this.idx);
},
changeSortIcon: function(elem){
     console.log(elem);
     var cls = (this.parent.collection.sortDirection === 1) ? this.sortUpIcon : this.sortDownIcon;
     elem.removeClass(this.sortUpIcon)
         .removeClass(this.sortDownIcon)
         .addClass(cls);
}
```

The console not show error but, the icon class not change. Console log of "elem" return the "i" element:

```
[i.icon-arrow-up pull-right, prevObject: x.fn.x.init[1], context: undefined, selector: "i", jquery: "1.10.2", constructor: function…]
```

Note: this.sortUpIcon and this.sortDownIcon are defined.

Comment: What is `this.sortUpIcon`, a string?

Comment: Are you positive that 'this' is the correct this when the function is run? Try outputting them. Also, be aware that the class attribute might not look like it has been changed in the source view, but might have actually been changed in code.

Comment: Are you sure this condition `(this.parent.collection.sortDirection === 1) ` can be true ? Is `this.parent.collection.sortDirection` really an integer ? If your `<i>` elemnt is initialized with one of the two classes, you can reduce your `changeSortIcon` method's body to  a single line, using `toggleClass`.